# Does WordPress do something that overrides .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working locally on a WordPress site for a client. The client keeps their install of wordpress in the server root, but because I have more than one client, I like to install everything in a client folder, like localhost/client. Normally it's a simple matter to add a rewrite rule to .htaccess, setting the rewrite base to be `/client/`. But today it's not working at all. Even if I put nonsense in the rewrite rule, the site works (which it should not, if the rewrite rules are in effect). The images references are still looking for root at localhost/, instead of localhost/client/, which means they are broken.

I looked into WordPress's documentation and found it has something called WP_rewrite, and there is a place to set parameters for it in wp-includes/rewrite.php). I set the  `root` parameter to `client/` but that doesn't seem to have any effect either.

One last thing: there is an .htaccess file in localhost/client/, and another one in localhost/client/wp/. I have them both set to `RewriteBase = /client/`, but I've tried just about every other sensible combination--no change.

So my question is: does WordPress do something else that would make the rewrite rules I set in .htaccess not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a small change to your local environment for a more flexible solution. Use virtual hosts. If you're running WAMP/MAMP, this tool is readily available to you. It allows you run a directory within your localhost as its own site, which you can access using a local-only URL of your choosing. I have my sites set up as sitename.local, for instance, so they all live in their own happy little ecosystem. Highly recommended.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it solved my problem at once, with no need to change any settings. Ivan's answer was also a good one, but I think this is a better suggestion, and I'm surprised WordPress doesn't suggest this option themselves. I knew about virtual hosts but thought it was more of a convenience thing for developers who liked that; now I see how useful they are. Much appreciated.

Comment: Question though--why the .local; is that just a convention you like?

Comment: Absolutely, just a convention I use. You could use anything. Using .local just clearly defined a result from the address bar as a local site, and in general the standardisation means I know that a site's local URL is as long as I know its current or future live URL. But to answer your question, it's my choosing, and you can name any local site whatever you want.

Comment: +1 Yeah. I use domain.dev :) WP does not list in codex because it is general dev issue, nothing to do with WP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, you have to make some steps that will change entries in db before you move it to subfolder.
Here are detailed info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site

What you need to do:

1. copy everything as it is setup on your clients server i.e. in root folder
2. do the steps in above url, important are 4. & 5.; step 10. actually just go to permalink settings and click on "Save" button (or "Update" I do not remember how it says)

Now you can work :)
Are you modifying only theme or what?

Comment: Very good answer; thank you for pointing me to the right place in the WordPress documentation (there is so much of it that it's often hard to find things). For the record though, I did follow the steps, and it didn't fix my problem. Something else is going on. Still, I also endorse this answer as the best first tep to fixing an issue with folder locations.